# Azure Devops: Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\s\**\*.zip

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up my first pipeline to deploy a web app to an Azure App service. I am able to manually publish the site via Visual Studio but now I am trying to get it build and deploy from an Azure Repo. The build part works fine and without errors. The problem comes in when I add in the deploy task. The deploy task doesn't seem to be able to find the file/s to deploy.

My Pipeline
[image]

My Publish config:
[image]
In my Pipeline the Publish section shows the following debug info:

> ##[debug]Exit code 0 received from tool 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
> ##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
> ##[debug]modifyOutputPath=true
> ##[debug]Zip Source: D:\a\1\a\s
> ##[debug]Zip arguments: Source: D:\a\1\a\s , target: D:\a\1\a\s.zip
> ##[debug]Successfully created archive D:\a\1\a\s.zip
> ##[debug]rm -rf D:\a\1\a\s
> ##[debug]removing directory D:\a\1\a\s

The Publish Artifact config section:
[image]

The Publish Artifact section shows the following success message:

> File upload succeed.
> Upload 'D:\a\1\a' to file container: '#/10370704/drop'
> Associated artifact 541 with build 667

The Web Deployment config looks like this:
[image]

Then the Azure Web App Deployment shows the following debug and error message:

> ##[debug]pattern: 'D:\a\1\s***.zip'
>
> ##[debug]expanding braces
>
> ##[debug]pattern: 'D:/a/1/s/**/*.zip'
> ##[debug]applying include pattern against original list
> ##[debug]0 matches
> ##[debug]0 final results
> ##[debug]No matching files were found with search pattern: D:\a\1\s***.zip
>
> ##[debug]Deployment Failed with Error: Error: No package found with specified pattern:
> D:\a\1\s***.zip
> Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.
> ##[debug]task result: Failed
> ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\s***.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use powershell task to list the files in the folder before publish the  Azure Web App.

From your description, it seems the pattern should be `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.zip`?